# How to handle long complex SQL update query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this code that never finishes executing.

Here is what happens:

1. We make an API call to get large data and we need to check to see if any difference from our database, we need to update our DB for that specific row. Row numbers will increase as the project grows, could go even over 1 billion rows in some cases.

**Issue is making this scalable that even in 1 billion row update, it works**

2. To simulate it I did 9000 for loop

```
<?PHP 
ini_set("memory_limit","-1");
 ignore_user_abort(true);
for ($i=0; $i < 9000; $i++) { 
  // Complex SQL UPDATE query that requires joining tables,
  // and doing search and update if matches several variables
}

//here I have log function to see if for loop has been finished
```

If I loop it 10 times, it still takes time but it works and records, but with 9000 it doesn't finish the loop and never records anything.

Note: I added `ini_set("memory_limit","-1"); ignore_user_abort(true);` to prevent memory errors.

Is there any way to make this scalable?

**Details:** I do this query 2 times a day

Comment: Are you saying that there's a chance you'll retrieve over a billion pieces of data from an API that need to be updated in your local DB? How often will you do this check, and are you sure your system has enough memory to store all that in one API call, or are you breaking it into several calls? I'd also check your schema to see if you can reduce the number of rows you're storing.

Comment: @kmoser At some point in a project that would be the case, but even now 9000 rows is a very near-future possibility. There is no way to decrease the number of rows. The solution I think might help is run SQL query 100 times then send webhook to same page with one hint saying do SQL after nth row. Do you think it would work or it is not the best solution here?

Comment: Your script may be timing out if you don't use PHP's `set_time_limit(0)`.

Comment: @kmoser good idea, let me try

Comment: @kmoser do you think it is a good idea after 100 rows, to webhook page itself to say update next 100 instead of doing all in one page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by webhook. Is this running on a web page? That's really not the right way to run a cron job. See my answer below for how I suggest you have this run. Processing all rows from memory is a recipe for failure since the script has no way to pick up where it left off if it stops partway through for any reason.

Comment: I am using web cron jobs (a website that sends a request to special URL every 12 hours) to make this call 2 times a day, and what I mean by webhook is that sending a post request to page itself to continue next 100 rows @kmoser

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the specifics of the API, how often you call it, how much data it's returning at a time, and how much information you actually have to store, it's hard to give you specific answers. In general, though, I'd approach it like this:

Have a "producer" script query the API on whatever basis you need, but instead of doing your complex SQL update, have it simply store the data locally (presumably in a table, let's call it `tempTbl`). That should ensure it runs relatively fast. Implement some sort of timestamp on this table, so you know when records were inserted. In the ideal world, the next time this "producer" script runs, if it encounters any data from the API that already exists in `tempTbl`, it will overwrite it with the new data (and update the last updated timestamp). This ensures `tempTbl` always contains the latest cached updates from the API.

You'll also have a "consumer" script which runs on a regular basis and which processes the data from `tempTbl` (presumably in LIFO order, but could be in any order you want). This "consumer" script will process a chuck of, say, 100 records from `tempTbl`, do your complex SQL UPDATE on them, and delete them from `tempTbl`.

The idea is that one script ("producer") is constantly filling `tempTbl` while the other script ("consumer") is constantly processing items in that queue. Presumably "consumer" is faster than "producer", otherwise `tempTbl` will grow too large. But with an intelligent schema, and careful throttling of how often each script runs, you can hopefully maintain stasis.

I'm also assuming these two scripts will be run as cron jobs, which means you just need to tweak how many records they process at a time, as well as how often they run. Theoretically there's no reason why "consumer" can't simply process all outstanding records, although in practice that may put too heavy a load on your DB so you may want to limit it to a few (dozen, hundred, thousand, or million?) records at a time.

Comment: We call this API 2 times a day

Comment: Is the script which processes the API data able to finish running in less than 12 hours, i.e. before it is called again?

Comment: Yes it should be, but in the future, if it doesn't it is easy to fix just having a flag that says last updates made in X timestamp, so we check if it is more than 12 hours, we check after few hours again

Comment: why we should have 2 SQL database instead of doing this with multiple requests like this:
1)  Page get called 2 times a day normally.
2) Page updated 100 rows then send a request to itself without waiting for a response, and in that request, it sends whatever it already got from API, and says update next 100 rows, so it happens recursively till all rows have been updated. 

What do you think about this?

Comment: That might work but it relies on the web connection not failing, the browser not hanging, the machine you're running the browser on not crashing/failing/powering off, etc. If this is an important job, I'd run it directly on a server, not a PC. It also relies on all rows being processed before 12 hours, otherwise it will always be falling behind. I don't know if order matters here, so you're better able to address that than I am.